# In search for js framework that support svg elements binding

Tags: javascript, svg

Does anyone ever tried to work with attribute data bindings with svg objects?

for example:

lets say I got a rect and want to bind it's x property to a path, I need some view object, that sits in my js and can be bounded to this 2 objects, one for the x attribute of the rect and one to the d attribute of the path, with a converter that can take the "m 1,1 ..."
and replace the first 1 with the x value of the rect.

Does anybody know a framework to support this requirements?

Comment: What have you looked at and what have you dismissed? What, if any, research have you done? I'm not, personally, convinced that this is on-topic for this site; but if you could at least show some effort that'd help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which JavaScript framework (jQuery vs Dojo vs ... )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs)

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you jQuery.

jQuery is one of the best frameworks on the planet.

It's super easy to use. You can almost find any solutions to your future problems on the web while the jQuery tech community is so powerful.

All your basic requirements can be fulfilled by jQuery or its plugins. However while your app goes further, you should make your own customizations as the same situation with any framework. But with jQ, your customization will be easy too.

Regard frameworks as a tool especially in front-end development. What you need is an easy to use, robust framework to get things done. The architecture in you application relies on your own codes instead of frameworks.

Maybe jQuery is the best choice to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a function called getPointAtLength to derive a pair of coordinates Along a path

Here is the link to the Raphael function which you can play with there..

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2
And look specifically at a function called Element.getPointAtLength

Comment: nice util, can help me, but not the framework I need, hard to manage objects after you draw them.